# New Swift, or Xcode bug

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

So attached I have a breakdown of the issue that I am experiencing, with annotations and notes on the views, and the actual images of the code that I see. Recently I updated to the latest Xcode, and altered my swift syntax. I did not convert to swift 3, but 2.3 (I think) it's currently on. Please see the image for full explanation!!! Anything helps!!

[Tap here to view the image](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rby7i0u9vYBH5Ao7tYi94ToDkooTdAO-aMpkrwNpzmM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Don't post images of code, post code. Helps others search after you.

Comment: I will make the adjustment!